# Close bootstrap modal after ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, grails

Im working on a login page using `Grails` `<formRemote>` tag and `Bootstrap Modal`
Everything works except I don't know how to close de modal after login success.

with:

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide')
```

On login fail I update **#modal-body** with the errorMessage returned by my controller (*LoginController*) and that is fine but when login success (**ajaxSuccess** method in *LoginController*) I redirect to the home page and I don't know how to tell the modal to close at this time.

Some help would be very appreciated.

Here is the form template snippet that send the **AJAX** Call.

```
<g:formRemote  url="[controller:'j_spring_security_check', action:'']"
    name="loginForm"
    update="modal-body"
    class="form-inline"
    on401="alert('error');">
    <input type="text" name="j_username"  class="input" placeholder="email" autocomplete="on" value="" id="j_username">
    <input type="password" name="j_password" class="input" placeholder="password" value="" id="j_password">
    <input  id="loginButton" type="submit" value="Login" class="btn"
        data-trigger="manual" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true"  data-content="<span></span>" />
    <div class="login-message" id="login-message">${message}</div>
</g:formRemote>

<script>
    <g:if test="${message == 'success'}">
        $(function() {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        });
    </g:if>
</script>
```

Here is the **Bootstrap Modal** snippet that render the loginForm template inside **#modal-body**

```java
<div id="cont">
    <div class="modal fade hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-remote="">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Login/Register</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="modal-body" class="modal-body">
            <g:render template="/login/templates/loginForm"></g:render>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is **authfail** and **ajaxSuccess** method from the *LoginController*

```
def authfail = {
    def username = session[UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY]
    String errorMessage = ''
    def exception = session[WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION]

    if (exception) {
        if (exception instanceof AccountExpiredException) {
                errorMessage = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.expired")
            }
            else if (exception instanceof CredentialsExpiredException) {
                errorMessage = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.passwordExpired")
            }
            else if (exception instanceof DisabledException) {
                errorMessage = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.disabled")
            }
            else if (exception instanceof LockedException) {
                errorMessage = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.locked")
            }
            else {
                errorMessage = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.fail")
            }
        }
        if (springSecurityService.isAjax(request)) {
            render(template: '/login/templates/loginForm', model: [message:errorMessage])
            //render(errorMessage)
        }
    else {
        render view: '/index' , params: params
        //redirect action: 'auth', params: params
        //render([error: msg] as JSON)
    }
}
```

This is the **ajaxsuccess** method

```
def ajaxSuccess = {  
    render(template: '/login/templates/loginForm', model: [message:"success"])        
}
```

I keep the commented line so you can see what I tried to do.

Thank in advance

Comment: why do you set a variable that exists? <g:set var="errorMessage" value="${errorMessage}" />

Comment: yes thanks, I should get rid of this one. But I don't think that resolve my problem :)

Comment: I juste removed it from my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your gsp looks somehow like this :

```
<div id="modal-body">
   <g:render template="/login/templates/loginForm" model="[errorMessage:'none']" />
</div>

<g:formRemote ....
```

you could simply add some javascript to your template, it will run when the Dom is completely updated with ajax response
and make sure the errorMessage variable is set initialy like above to "none"

```
    <div id="cont">
        <div class="modal fade hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-remote="">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">Login/Register</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="modal-body" class="modal-body">
                <g:render template="/login/templates/loginForm"></g:render>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        <g:if test="${errorMessage == 'success'}">
            // it will only close if the errorMessage from ajax is 'success, wich by the way is not an error ^^
            $(function() {
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            });
        </g:if>
    </script>
```

Comment: i i see i read your code wrong, you could simply add the script part to your  "login/templates/loginForm.gsp and make sure you set the variable errorMessage first like  <g:render template="/login/templates/loginForm" model="[errorMessage:'none']" /></g:render>

Comment: Ok I will try now and get back with the result. Thank you

Comment: Ok I have Updated my code and it is working ! Thank you @john to have  get me on the way.